# Resize jQuery colorbox for iframe content?

Tags: jquery, colorbox

Using resize() function, we can resize ajax content of colorbox. But how to resize width and height of colorbox having iframe content? can it be possible to set new height and width of colobox?

I found solution from this url - http://groups.google.com/group/colorbox/browse_thread/thread/fadc3d68ca764de3/c38fa24136a6abd7?pli=1

but stop with another issue, onComplete event called before iframe content load completely.
I have tried with setTimeout function to put some waiting for content to load. But it's not concrete solution as network speed vary to get response.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("yourelement").colorbox({
  iframe: true,
  innerWidth: 600,
  innerHeight: 400
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

From v1.3.8, you can set width, height, innerWidth and innerHeight of colorbox using resize() method.

Answer (score 0):

From parent

```
parent.$.colorbox.resize({innerHeight:"260px"});
```

Answer (score 0):

as to the second part. you can try fastiframe false,
element.colorbox({fastiframe:false});

setting it to false will prevent it from rendering before loading the iframe and it is true by default.

found it here:
http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/